# Sed and Awk - Adding a line to config file

Tags: sed, awk

I need to add partition to a config file using `sed` and `awk`. How can i do that ?
like lets say I have a path `/test1` in the partition `/dev/sda3` and I need to add `/dev/sda3` to a config file with its name(part3). Lets assume config file is `configtest.config`
I need to add to in the third line of `configtest.config` following :

```
part3  /dev/sda3
```

How can I do that using `sed` and `awk` ? I know to read the partition 
i.e

```
df /test1 | awk '/^\/dev/ {$1}'
```

I get

```
/dev/sda3
```

but I do not know how to add this partition to third line of config file with its name (part3)

I want to use `sed` and `awk`.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

```
var=$(df /test1 | sed -rn '2s@([^0-9]+([0-9]+)).*@part\2 \1@p')
sed -i "3i $var" configtest.config
```

Comment: Thanks ! That is great. What would sed command look like if I have to change crashkernelvalue=256M@32M from crashkernel=128M@16M

Answer (score 0):

```
df /test1 |
awk 'NR==FNR{if (/^\/dev/) part=$1; next} 1; FNR==3{print "part3",part}' - configtest.config
```

If you want to overwrite the original file with the result then it's just:

```
df /test1 |
awk 'NR==FNR{if (/^\/dev/) part=$1; next} 1; FNR==3{print "part3",part}' - configtest.config > tmp &&
mv tmp configtest.config
```